# Remap Super+Left to the Home button

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce, xdotool, remapping, xbindkeys

I want to remap Super+Left key combination to the Home button. I tried tools like xdotools, xte and xbindkeys, but for some weird reason it worked only on Firefox, and not on any other window.

Someone knows what is the best way to achieve this?

P.S
I'm using Xubuntu 18.04, but I will welcome a solution that works in any desktop environment.

Comment: Super+Left Home means: press the left super key and while holding, press Home. Please clarify your title if this is not what you intended. And then, what is the button in your title? Make your title clearly reflect the question.

Comment: Sorry I edit the title. I meant to re-map Super+Left key combination to Home